# How to export multi-line cells to CSV file

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, csv

I have an XSLX file where some rows have multiple lines, for example:

```
test
test1
test2
```

When I'm trying to export (using menu "Save As") this file as CSV or Excel workbook (1997-2003), Excel substitutes multi-line cell's value with a lot of hash symbols

```
################...##
```

Are there any ways to export these file to CSV file without skipping such cells?

I see hashes in Excel (because it doesn't fit the cell) and in any text editor used to open the CSV file after exporting XSLX as CSV.

Comment: I've add a couple of details in my question. I see hashes in Excel (xlsx) and in any text editor (csv). Hashes in Excel is not a problem definitely.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is solved.

I added "`" at the beginning of each cell using VB. After that I change cell format from "text" to "number". After these manipulations file was correctly saved to csv format.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not just because the cells are too small for the contents? For example, if I put `121221312121121221` into an Excel cell, then make the cell smaller, at a certain point all the numbers in the cells turn into `####`.

It's probably because CSV files don't hold any type of table width data. If you open the CSV in Notepad, your data will probably be there.

Have you tried dragging the cells of the CSV file bigger? This should make the data appear. If this is the problem, it is only a temporary measure though, as CSVs don't save cell width data.